# Get a list of SharePoint SiteCollection Owners along with their e-mail and the URL of the Site with Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, owner, sitecollection

I am currently working on a script that connects to our SharePoint Admin Center and returns a list of all sites with all of the owners (name and e-mail)

I tried multiple solutions with PnP and SP, but nothing really seems to work.

It seems that I have to loop over all sites, get the web object with properties, get the permission levels, filter them for "Full Control", and then look for every member with these permissions. But it kind of doesn't work like that?

Has anyone else encountered this topic yet?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround which may help you somehow. Here is a script which exports a .csv file containing all the groups with full control role in each site collection. You can use the list to [get all the group members](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/04/get-office-365-group-members-using-powershell.html), and they definitely have full control permission. And for site collection administrators who have full control permission, just use the [Get-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpsitecollectionadmin?view=sharepoint-ps)

```
$admin = "jerry@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
$Credentials=Get-Credential
Connect-SPOService -Url https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com -credential $Credentials
$Sites=Get-SPOSite
$OwnerList=@() 
Foreach($Site in $Sites)
{
     
            Write-Host $site.URL -ForegroundColor Cyan
     
            #Get all Groups from the site permissions
            $sitegroups = Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site $site.URL
     
            #Get Group info and members that have site owners permissions
            foreach ($sitegroup in $sitegroups)
            {
                foreach($role in $sitegroup.Roles)
                {
                try{
                    if ( $role.Contains(“Full Control”) )
                    {
                        $Row=""|Select SiteURL, FullControlGroupName;
                        $Row.SiteURL=$site.URL
                        $Row.FullControlGroupName=$sitegroup.title
                        $OwnerList+=$Row
                    }
                 }
                 catch{
                    write-host "$($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red
                 }
                }
            }
}
$OwnerList | Export-Csv "C:\\OwnerList.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```